# Continuity condition in locally convex F - spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

It is well known that if $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, then if the linear map $T:X→Y$ satisfies the condition $f∘T ∈ X^{*}$ for every $f∈Y^{*}$, then T is bounded. Is the conclusion still true under assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are locally convex F - spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The continuity of all $f\circ T$ implies that $T$ has closed graph: If $x_n\to 0$ and $Tx_n\to y$ then we have to show $y=0$. But the continuity of $f$ and $f\circ T$ imply $f(y)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(T(x_n))=f(T(0))=0$; as this holds for all $f\in Y^*$ we get $y=0$ from Hahn-Banach. The closed graph theorem thus implies that $T$ is continuous.